# Open and close a component Angular 4 it is not working as excepted

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have created a component like popup but I am facing with a problem there.
When I open this component and then click cancel it hides but then I need to click 2 times edit to open again the component and If I click to edit an item and in the popup click cancel and then anothr one to edit both of them are active.
And please if someone don't understand question write in comment or make a edit suggestion.

This is my code.

This is the parent Component

```
<app-edit-dialog-vi *ngIf="showChild" [data]="dataToPass" [showMePartially]="showChild"></app-edit-dialog-vi>
<div class="dropdown-menu-item" (click)="edit({valueItem: valueItem})">{{'button.#edit'|translate}}</div>


 <div [class]="'name-block name-block-width-' + valueItem.level" [ngClass]="{active: activeSelected === valueItem.id}" (click)="toggleExpand()">
    {{valueItem.name}} </div>


showChild = false;
activeSelected: any = '';

edit(editOptions: EditViOptions) {
  this.showChild = !this.showChild;
  console.log(this.showChild, '##');
  if (editOptions.valueItem || editOptions.appendToParentId) {
    this.dataToPass = editOptions;
    this.activeSelected = editOptions.valueItem.id;
  }
}
```

This is the popup

```
<div *ngIf="showMePartially" class="container">
</div>

  @Input() showMePartially = true;
  @Input() data: EditViOptions = null;


cancel() {
    this.showMePartially = false;

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 way binding for show me partially:

```
<app-edit-dialog-vi *ngIf="showChild" [data]="dataToPass" [(showChild)]="showChild" (emitToRemove)="activeTab = 0"></app-edit-dialog-vi>
edit(editOptions: EditViOptions) {
  this.showChild = true;
}
```

In this component u set `showMePartially` to `true` on click.

Then in popup component, u have input and output:

```
@Input() showChild: boolean;
@Output() showChildChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

And on close:

```
this.showChildChange.emit(false)
```

For changing selected item:

```
<div click="changeTab(1)" *ngIf="activeTab === 1">First Active</div>
<div click="changeTab(2)" *ngIf="activeTab === 2">Second Active</div>

activeTab = 1;
changeTab(active){
  this.activeTab = active;
}
```

If you need to change or remove active state when u close the popup, on close emit something:

```
@Output() emitToRemove = new EventEmitter();
```

and I added in code at the start listener for output.

Comment: It is working but I have another problem here, If I edit The edited ID is active but If I click Cancel and there another id to edit both of them are active. I will change the code to be more specific

Comment: @ZhuniqiA Im not sure I understand what u are trying to say :)

Comment: I have changed the code, so when I click to edit item in the parent changes the style but when I click cnacel in the popup and in the parent another Item trying to edit the last one and this new for editing are active, how can I do only for one to be active

Comment: @ZhuniqiA edited my answer, try that, keep your code for edit, just change the showChild variable

Comment: But I have asked for the activeSelected, or maybe I didnt understand good your answer ?

Comment: I have fixed with the same way like showmePartially only chnaged the function to activeSelected :)